# Как в Moment.js вывести список месяцев на русском языке?

Tags: javascript, дата, momentjs

Необходимо получить массив, содержащий названия месяцев на русском языке. С помощью библиотеки `Moment.js` я могу получить массив английских названий месяцев:

```
month = moment.monthsShort()
```

Есть ли аналогичная функция для получения списка месяцев на русском языке?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493309/how-do-i-change-the-language-of-moment-js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего это достичь при помощи библиотеки `moment-with-locales.js` вместо `moment.js`, поскольку в ней имеется метод locale(). Небольшой пример:

```
moment.locale('ru');

let months = document.getElementsByClassName('months')[0],
monthsList = moment.monthsShort(),
monthsElement = document.createElement('li');
monthsElement.classList.add('months-item');

monthsList.forEach(function(element) {
    monthsElement.innerText = element;
    months.appendChild(monthsElement.cloneNode(true));
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pa4nh7xt/